# Query In a detail view

Tags: django, django-views

There is a detail view displayed in a form of table. I want a write a search query that displays the found result. The data is displayed in a tabular form and has a search on the top. ClientInfo is the table that has all the information about the client.

Models.py

```
class ClientInfo(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    insurance_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cpt_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    update = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    update_by = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Detail.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

<tr>
    <th scope="col"><small>INCURANCE NAME</small></th>
    <th scope="col"><small>CPT-CODE</small></th>
    <th scope="col"><small>SUBJECT</small></th>
    <th scope="col"><small>UPDATE</small></th>
    <th scope="col"><small> DATE</small> </th>
    <th scope="col"><small> UPDATE DATE</small> </th>
    <th scope="col"><small> UPDATED BY</small> </th>
    <th scope="col"><small>Edit</small></th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   {% for item in client.clientinfo_set.all %}
    <td><small> {{ item.insurance_name }}</small></td>
    <td><small>{{ item.cpt_code }}</small></td>
  <td><small> {{ item.subject }}</small></td>
    <td><small><p>{{ item.update }}</p></small></td>
    <td><small><p>{{ item.date }}</p></small></td>
    <td><small>{{ item.update_date }}</small></td>
    <td><small>{{ item.update_by }}</small></td>
    <td><small></small><a href="">Edit Info</a></td>

  </tr>
  <br>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

view.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'update/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_client'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Clients.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'client'
    model = Clients
    template_name = 'update/detail.html'

class ClientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Clients
    fields = '__all__'
    class ClientInfoCreate(CreateView):
    model = ClientInfo
    fields = '__all__'

class ClientUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Clients
    fields = '__all__'

class ClientInfoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ClientInfo
    fields = '__all__'

class searchClientInfo(generic.DeleteView):
    model = ClientInfo
    template_name = 'update:detail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = 
        return context
```

I want to retrieve any row that matches to the search user puts in the searchbox

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    input = forms.CharField()
```

> I want to retrieve any row that matches to the search user puts in the searchbox.

You don't necessarily need to use `DetailView` if you are just planning on retrieving any row that matches the search. You can just use TemplateView.

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from MyApp.forms import SearchForm 

class MyView(generic.TemplateView,FormMixin):
    template_name="update/client.html"
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            context['clientinfo'] = ClientInfo.objects
                    .filter([yourfield]=form.cleaned_data['input'])
        else:
            context['clientinfo'] = ClientInfo.objects.all()
        return context
```

Note: This does not include AJAX. If you want to include that you will need to read up on how AJAX works first and how to integrate that with your Django views.